# Problema al llenar una lista personalizada con datos de una tabla SQLITE

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, arraylist, android-listview

Al momento de realizar una consulta esta se visualiza bien en un `ListView` normal, pero cuando cambio el `ListView` por una lista personalizada tengo algunos problemas.

El problema es que en la consulta los datos están en una línea generada por el cursor y en la lista personalizada los datos se llenan uno por uno.

Adjunto  código.

Código de la **clase que personaliza la lista**

```
package com.example.aguila0017.auxiliarcompras;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;   
import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 /**
  * Created by Aguila0017 on 7/09/2017.
*/

public class ListaPersonalizada  extends BaseAdapter {


    Context context;
    ArrayList lista;
   String id;
     String  nombre;
    String valor;
    String cantidad;
    String total;
    String dia;
    String mes;
    String ano;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListaPersonalizada(Activity context, String  id, String  nombre, String  valor, String  cantidad,String  total, String  dia, String  mes, String  ano) {
        this.context = context;
        //this.lista = lista;
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.total = total;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return id.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        TextView txt4;
        TextView txt5;
        TextView txt6;
        TextView txt7;
        TextView txt8;

        //http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listapersonalizada, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txt1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        txt2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_PRODUCTO);
        txt3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TXTvalor);
        txt4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCANTIDAD);
        txt5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDIA);
        txt6 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMES);
        txt7 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAÑO);
        txt8 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);


        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txt1.setText(id);
        txt2.setText(nombre);
        txt3.setText(valor);
        txt4.setText(cantidad);
        txt8.setText(total);
        txt5.setText(dia);
        txt6.setText(mes);
        txt7.setText(ano);


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Código de la **clase principal** en la cual se intenta abrir la lista personalizada.

```
          package com.example.aguila0017.auxiliarcompras;

         import android.content.ContentValues;
         import android.content.Intent;
         import android.database.Cursor;
           import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
         import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; 
          import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
           import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
           import android.os.Bundle;
           import android.text.format.Time;
           import android.view.View;
           import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
           import android.widget.Button;
           import android.widget.EditText;
           import android.widget.ListView;
           import android.widget.Toast;

           import java.util.ArrayList;

          import java.util.Date;


           public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListaPersonalizada listaPersonalizada;

EditText et_nombre, et_cantidad, et_valor, et_total, et_acomulador;

int valor=0, total, cantiadad=0 , acomulador=0;

int dia,mes,ano;

int NOMBRE,CANTIDAD,VALOR,TOTAL,DIA,MES,ANO;
int ID;
ListView lista;

Button sumar, btn_ver, btn_NuevaCompra, btn_listaFechas;

ArrayList<String> listado, ListadoFechas;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);

    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    et_nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_NomProducto);
    et_cantidad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cantidad);
    et_valor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_valor);
    et_total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_total);
    et_acomulador=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_acomulador);
    sumar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_modifocar);
    btn_ver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ver);
    btn_NuevaCompra = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_NuevaCompra);
    btn_listaFechas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_LFechas);

    btn_listaFechas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Organizador.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_NuevaCompra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            int dia=today.monthDay;
            int mes = today.month;
            int year = today.month;

            mes = mes + 1;

            nuevaCompra(dia,mes,year);

            et_nombre.setText("");
            et_cantidad.setText("");
            et_valor.setText("");
            et_acomulador.setText("");
            et_total.setText("");
            acomulador=acomulador-acomulador;

        }
    });

    btn_ver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, lista.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonFloat);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            valor= Integer.valueOf(et_valor.getText().toString());
            cantiadad= Integer.valueOf(et_cantidad.getText().toString());
            total= valor*cantiadad;



            et_total.setText(""+total);

            acomulador = acomulador + total;

            et_acomulador.setText(""+acomulador);

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            ano=today.year;
            mes=today.month+1;
            dia = today.monthDay;




            guardar(et_nombre.getText().toString(),valor,cantiadad,total,acomulador,dia,mes,ano);


            et_nombre.setText("");
            et_cantidad.setText("");
            et_valor.setText("");

        }
    });


    /*Boton basico reemplazado por el floatbutton
     FUNCION: añade registros y hace el respectivo calculo de dar el total.

    sumar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            valor= Integer.valueOf(et_valor.getText().toString());
            cantiadad= Integer.valueOf(et_cantidad.getText().toString());
            total= valor*cantiadad;



         et_total.setText(""+total);

            acomulador = acomulador + total;

            et_acomulador.setText(""+acomulador);



            guardar(et_nombre.getText().toString(),valor,cantiadad,total,acomulador);


            et_nombre.setText("");
            et_cantidad.setText("");
            et_valor.setText("");

        }
    });
    */
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    Cargarlistado();
}

private void Cargarlistado() {

    listado = lista();

    listaPersonalizada = new ListaPersonalizada(MainActivity.this,lista());
    lista.setAdapter(listaPersonalizada);



private void guardar (String NOMBRE ,int VALOR, int CANTIDAD, int TOTAL ,int ACOMULADO, int DIA, int MES, int ANO){

    BaseHelper helper = new BaseHelper(this,"Demo",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    try{
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        c.put("Nombre",NOMBRE);
        c.put("Valor", VALOR);
        c.put("Cantidad",CANTIDAD);
        c.put("Total",TOTAL);
        c.put("Acomulado",ACOMULADO);
        c.put("DIA",DIA);
        c.put("MES",MES);
        c.put("ANO",ANO);

        db.insert("REGISTROS",null,c);
        db.close();

        Toast.makeText(this,"Articulo Ingresado.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Error: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private ArrayList<String> lista(){


    ArrayList<String>datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    BaseHelper helper = new BaseHelper(this,"Demo",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = "select Id, Nombre, Valor, Cantidad, Total, DIA, MES,ANO from Registros";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String linea = c.getInt(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+" "+c.getInt(2)+" "+c.getInt(3)+" "+c.getInt(4)+" "+c.getInt(5)+" "+c.getInt(6)+" "+c.getInt(7);
            datos.add(linea);



        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return datos;


}

private void nuevaCompra(int DIA, int MES, int YEAR){




    BaseHelper helper = new BaseHelper(this,"Fecha",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    try{
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        c.put("DIA",DIA);
        c.put("MES",MES);
        c.put("YEAR",YEAR);



        db.insert("FECHAS",null,c);
        db.close();

        Toast.makeText(this,"Nueva Compra en proceso...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Error: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Amigo puedes compartir el proyecto por favor estoy haciendo lo mismo pero no me sale tengo problemas al enviar los campos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo que te recomiendo es que crees un objeto en el que almacenes todos los datos obtenidos por el cursor de la base de datos y que pases ese objeto al adaptador del ListView personalizado. Ya en el adaptador obtienes todos los datos y los muestras en la interfaz grafica. De esa manera el constructor de tu adaptador no necesitara recibir tantos parametros.

Aunque si quieres saber el porque tu código no funciona, es porque al constructor del adaptador le estas pasando el array lista, cuando lo que este recibe es una gran cantidad de parámetros de tipo String, por lo que también tu código debe de dar error de sintaxis.

Bien aqui va la solucion.

#### Clase Datos

```
/*Objeto que almacena los datos obtenidos de la base de datos.*/

public class Datos {

    String id;
    String nombre;
    String valor;
    String cantidad;
    String total;
    String dia;
    String mes;
    String ano;

    public Datos (String  id, String nombre, String valor, String cantidad, 
        String total, String  dia, String mes, String ano) {

        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.total = total;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public void getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public void getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

}
```

#### Metodo lista()

```
private ArrayList<Datos> lista(){

    ArrayList<Datos> datos = new ArrayList<Datos>();
    BaseHelper helper = new BaseHelper(this,"Demo",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = "select Id, Nombre, Valor, Cantidad, Total, DIA, MES,ANO from Registros";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            // String linea = c.getInt(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+" "+c.getInt(2)+" "+c.getInt(3)+" "+c.getInt(4)+" "+c.getInt(5)+" "+c.getInt(6)+" "+c.getInt(7);
            datos.add(new Datos(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getInt(2), c.getInt(3),
                c.getInt(4), c.getInt(5), c.getInt(6), c.getInt(7)));

        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return datos;
}
```

#### ListaPersonalizada

```
public class ListaPersonalizada extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Datos> lista;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListaPersonalizada(Activity context, ArrayList<Datos> lista) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        TextView txt4;
        TextView txt5;
        TextView txt6;
        TextView txt7;
        TextView txt8;

        //http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listapersonalizada, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txt1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        txt2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_PRODUCTO);
        txt3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TXTvalor);
        txt4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCANTIDAD);
        txt5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDIA);
        txt6 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMES);
        txt7 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAÑO);
        txt8 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);

        // Obtienes los datos
        String id = lista.get(position).getId();
        String nombre = lista.get(position).getNombre();
        String valor = lista.get(position).getValor();
        String cantidad = lista.get(position).getCantidad();
        String total = lista.get(position).getTotal();
        String dia = lista.get(position).getDia();
        String mes = lista.get(position).getMes();
        String ano = lista.get(position).getAno();


        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txt1.setText(id);
        txt2.setText(nombre);
        txt3.setText(valor);
        txt4.setText(cantidad);
        txt8.setText(total);
        txt5.setText(dia);
        txt6.setText(mes);
        txt7.setText(ano);


        return itemView;
    }
}
```